# iframe website in wordpress is not showing full size

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have to embed a link website in my wordpress.
when its in different browser its not adapting to the device (eg, desktop, phones of different screen size)"responsive" width and height auto. on desktop its fine but phones its just cut off.

the padding-bottom is not a good idea. although it works find for phone but desktop with alot of whitespace.

```
.iframe-edm {
overflow: hidden; 
position: relative;  
}

.iframe-edm iframe { 
border: 0 ;
height: 100% ;
left: 0 ;
position: absolute ;
top: 0 ;
width: 100% ;}

<div class="iframe-edm"><iframe src="https://abc/index.php/edm?src=mci" 
marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

EDIT 1: After your comment, I made some edits in your code and it works fine on my WordPress page. I just added width=100% in iframe tag itself.

```
    <div class="iframe-edm"><iframe src="https://abc/index.php/edm?src=mci" 
      marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%">
      </iframe>
      </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but am not sure where to add it in the word press

Comment: I see you have html content in your code, you might have head tag, so you can add it there. If that doesn't work you might have to add media queries.

Comment: I tried to find the head tag but its no where to be found. this is not full developed from scratch word press. uses all in one seo? Please help am clueless.

Comment: Hi the page src="https://abc/index.php/edm?src=mci" already have the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> the problem it at the iframe in wordpress. the size needs to adapts to the device size not just cut off. on desktop its showing the entire embed link.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer, please check it out and let me know.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? And have you enabled debugging?

Comment: Hi Komal R, No errors.https://www.ramci.com.my/ the free book download page landing <div class="iframe-edm"><iframe src="https://www.mycreditinfo.com.my/index.php/edm?src=mci" width="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>